# Return number of rows looped through by MySQL when the search has a LIMIT?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have MySQL return the number of rows looked at?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE location like '%New York%' LIMIT 10
```

So in the example above, MySQL might loop through 30 rows in order to return these 10 results, this would indicate that the term "New York" is found approximately 1/3 of the time (assuming that the term is spread randomly). You could then tell the user that he can expect approx. X results before making him wait for the exact number. If there are ten million rows in the database then you could also assume that a count would take 1 million times longer than the above search and use that as the basis for a simple loading bar.

Comment: is this a realistic example?  usually you would care *which* 10 results, not just have a limit with no order by.

Comment: you can use sql_calc_found_rows to get the total number of rows that would have been found without the limit, but obviously that can take longer.  seems like you want a full text index for this anyway, though.

Comment: @ysth In MySQL 8.0, sql_calc_found_rows is deprecated. Anyway, I don't think that's what the OP is asking for. I think they want to know how many rows were examined, not how many rows matched.

Comment: @BillKarwin I read it as wanting to know how many rows were examined in order to estimate how many total would match

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack. I wouldn't use this in production code, but only for troubleshooting.

```
mysql> flush status;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show session status like 'handler_read%next';
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| Handler_read_next     | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next | 0     |
+-----------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable where location like '%New York%' limit 10;
+----+----------+
| id | location |
+----+----------+
|  1 | New York |
|  3 | New York |
|  4 | New York |
|  6 | New York |
|  8 | New York |
|  9 | New York |
| 13 | New York |
| 14 | New York |
| 17 | New York |
| 28 | New York |
+----+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show session status like 'handler_read%next';
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| Handler_read_next     | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next | 17    |
+-----------------------+-------+
```

This shows the number of times the handler API was invoked to read the next row. `Handler_read_rnd_next` indicates requests to read the next row during a table-scan (as would be used for your `LIKE` search with wildcards). `Handler_read_next` indicates requests to read the next row in index order when using an index.

Remember to use `flush status` to reset the counters to 0 before each query you want to measure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be helpful

SELECT count(location ) FROM table WHERE LOWER(location) LIKE "%New York%" GROUP BY location